# AngularJS toArray converts object keys to numbers

Tags: angularjs, filtering

I use angular-filter in my project to sort the output objects by page the problem is when I use syntax like this:

```
<ul class="catalog-list"
    ng-repeat="(key, value) in list | groupBy: 'styl' | toArray | orderBy:'page'">

  {{key}}

  <li ng-repeat="dziecko in value | filter:search | bookmark:search" 
      ng-class="{active:isActiveTab(dziecko)}"
      ng-click="openItem(dziecko)">
    {{dziecko.rodzina}}
    <b>{{dziecko.page}}</b>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Angular converts 'styl' properties ['nowoczesny','klasyczny'..] to numbers. Sorting works fine but I want to obtain names instead of numbers.

Comment: Where is the `groupBy` implementation that you are using? It's not built into Angular so you have to tell us how it works.

Comment: And where did you get `toArray`? Neither of these filters is built into Angular, so I'm not sure how you expect us to be able to answer your question.

Comment: I use angular-filter module to built this structure, everything works fine expect that {{key}} is sorting alpabetically, but I want to sort by 'page'.

Comment: The requirement you've described doesn't make much sense. You are grouping by `styl` which means that each `styl` group could have several different page values within it. How would one go about sorting such a thing? For example, what would be the result of sorting this by page: `[{styl1: [{page: 7}, {page: 3}]}, {styl2: [{page: 9}, {page: 1}]}, {styl3: [{page: 2}, {page: 8}]}]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`groupBy` return an object, and `orderBy` expect array as an argument, so that's the reason you should use `toArray` filter.

`toArray` work like that:
**Usage:** `object | toArray: addKey[optional]`
if addKey set to true, the filter also attaches a new property `$key` to the value containing the original key that was used in the object we are iterating over to reference the property

So, you can do something like this **example**, or take a look on the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/mukahonaxu/1/edit?html,js,output)

**JS:**

```
$scope.groups = [
    { category: 'alpha', id: 2 },
    { category: 'beta',  id: 3 }, 
    { category: 'gamma', id: 0 },
    { category: 'alpha', id: 4 },
    { category: 'beta',  id: 5 }, 
    { category: 'gamma', id: 1 }
   ];
```

**HTML:**

```
 <ul ng-repeat="group in groups | groupBy:'category' | toArray:true | orderBy:min">
    <!-- print the group name -->
    <li>{{ group.$key }}</li>
    <!-- iterate over the group members and order each group by id -->
    <li ng-repeat="item in group | orderBy:'id'">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

**RESULT:**

- **alpha**
- {"category":"alpha","id":2}
- {"category":"alpha","id":4}
- **beta**
- {"category":"beta","id":3}
- {"category":"beta","id":5}
- **gamma**
- {"category":"gamma","id":0}
- {"category":"gamma","id":1}

Comment: toArray + OrderBy doesn't seem to work on Chrome for very large objects. FF and IE however work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

An array has no named keys. It has integers as position. So don't use `toArray`.

Comment: Ok so what is another solution to sort output by page, by default Angular sorts alphabetically.