# toArray doesn't work fine with ui.bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-filters

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong that ui.bootstrap + angular.filter.groupBy + angular.filter.toArray don't work together ?

Example:
[http://plnkr.co/edit/G6sHrEHQIGVBwzolxlYb?p=preview][1]

```
[1]: http://plnkr.co/edit/G6sHrEHQIGVBwzolxlYb?p=preview
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/a/27484354/552194

PS: Here is the documentation for `toArray` https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#toarray

I am not sure if `groupBy` and `toArray` are meant to be used together like that ...

Comment: Seeing how in the duplicate you linked it's used exactly like that, it should be doable.